# Stop Chrome from changing tab background colour when out of focus

Tags: windows, google-chrome, tabs

When a Chrome window loses focus, it changes the background of tabs to a less-contrasty one, where the inactive tab colour becomes a *very* light gray:

| Chrome window has focus | Chrome window doesn't have focus |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Picture showing contrast between active and inactive tab] | [image: Picture showing lack of contrast between active and inactive tabs] |

This makes it difficult to see at a glance what the active tab is, if the window isn't currently in focus (e.g. if you're working in a different application on a dual-monitor setup).

Is it possible to disable this behavior, so that the background color of the tabs remains the same whether the window has focus or not?

Comment: I must be blind. They look identical

Comment: @Ramhound When Chrome is in-focus, inactive tabs have background `#dee1e6` - when out of focus they have background `#e8eaed`. Depending on your screen the latter may look almost identical to white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I couldn't find an option to disable the behavior entirely, it is possible to manipulate it using [Chrome themes](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/themes/).

By setting the `background_tab_inactive` and `frame_inactive` colors to the ones used when the window is in focus (`#dee1e6`/`rgb(222,225,230)` in my case, with the default Chrome look), those colors will also be used when the window is out of focus.

Such a theme can be used by saving the following JSON as `manifest.json`, navigating to `chrome://extensions`, enabling developer mode, clicking "Load unpacked", and choosing the directory containing the JSON file.

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "Custom theme",
  "theme": {
    "images": {},
    "colors": {
      "frame_inactive": [222, 225, 230],
      "background_tab_inactive": [222, 225, 230]
    },
    "tints": {},
    "properties": {}
  }
}
```

| Chrome window has focus (w/ custom theme) | Chrome window doesn't have focus (w/ custom theme) |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Image showing contrast between tabs] | [image: Image showing same contrast between tabs] |

Comment: That is valid, and there are other ways, as well, e.g., tab groups: https://www.guidingtech.com/change-tab-color-in-chrome/ userCrome.css also worked, at one time.